# Mongo 3.0, geospatial data and calculating distance

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Currently I spend another hour trying to figure out what wrong is with my queries.

Using Mongo version 3.0 I have two points which i checked are no further than 17000 meters. Unfortunately while trying to get them from db using distance up to 18000 meters I got nothing.

I tried "2dsphere" and/or "2d" indexes:

```
db.location.ensureIndex( { position : "2dsphere" } )
```

or

```
db.location.ensureIndex( { position : "2d" } )
```

Then I worked with:

```
    db.location.find( {
   position: { $near: [ 40.705395, -73.891104 ],  $maxDistance: 18000 }
} )
```

or

```
db.location.find( {
   position:  
   {
      $near : {
        $geometry : { 
          type : "Point" , 
          coordinates : [ 40.705395, -73.891104 ]  
        }, 
        $maxDistance : 18000
      }
    }
    })
```

and with:

```
db.location.find(    { location : { $near : [ 40.705395, -73.891104 ], $maxDistance: 18000 } } )
```

I had:

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=distance.location limit=0 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=18000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query",
    "code" : 17007
}
```

Example document:

```
> db.location.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5504ba8a97b3b27d56dc4045"), "id" : 123, "position" : [ 40.705562, -73.898818 ] }
```

Frankly speaking I can not find where my problem is. Calculation made by database seems to be wrong but I would rather say I made some sort of mistake.

Have You ever encountered simillar case?

Comment: Could you post a sample document with the location data?

Comment: @ZeMoon: I have just added "Example document" above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [2DSphere index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) on your collection in order to carry out geospatial queries.

```
db.location.ensureIndex({position:"2dsphere"});
```

Also, I noticed that you are storing the coordinates as [ 40.705562, -73.898818 ]. In MongoDB, the coordinate axis order is [ longitude, latitude ] according to which your coordinates lie somewhere in Antarctica. You need to store the coordinates like [ -73.898818, 40.705562 ] (Unless you really are storing the location from Antarctica).

Comment: Thank you. I do not know why I have never and nowhere noticed axis order. Everything seems to work now.